# What's the difference in pronunciation between "yo" and "you" in pinyin?

Tags: pronunciation, pinyin

I have no idea, for example, of what the difference in pronunciation between 唷 when pronounced with the first tone and 优.
If there's no difference, why are they written differently in pinyin?

Comment: kind of short vowel and long vowel

Comment: you has a ew after the oh. "oh" vs "oh-ew"

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference.

- 唷 (Toneless [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet): **/jɔ/**) rhymes with 波. The rhyme is the [open-mid back rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_rounded_vowel#Occurrence), and is the ***ough*** in American English *th**ough**t*.
- 優 (/**joʊ̯**/) rhymes with 秋. The rhyme is the [diphthong oʊ̯](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong#English), and almost the same as ***ow*** in American English *l**ow***.

Comment: Thanks mate, that's a very good explanation.

Comment: In some topolectical pinyin you will see "yo" written "yuo," (think: guo/luo/tuo, etc.) to mark the /o/ sound (注: ㄛ). Maybe that'll help wrap your mind around it.

Answer (score -1):

唷 is an exclamation, commonly accompanied by !!!!. This means a rising, stretched out tone.

It's like "high"  and "Hi!!!"

Comment: Not the Dv'er, but I think you should rephrase this a bit. When you say `It's like "high" and "Hi!!!"`, you're implying that the difference between 唷 and 優 is like the difference between "high" and "hi!!!", which is not the case. "Hi!!!" sounds exactly the same as "High!!!", whereas no amount of mood flavouring or excitement can turn 優！！！ into 唷！！！ - they simply don't rhyme.